# How do I verify that a string supplied file path is in a valid directory format?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I have a reasonably straight-forward question here but I seem to find myself revisiting each time I have to deal with the validation of file paths and names. So I'm wondering if there is a method available in `System.IO` or some other library in the framework that can make my life easier!?

Lets take the contrived example of a method that takes a file path and a filename and from these inputs it formats and returns unique full file-location.

```
public string MakeFileNameUnique(string filePath, string fileName)
{
    return filePath + Guid.NewGuid() + fileName;
}
```

I know that I must do the following to get the path in a correct format so that I can append the guid and filename:

- if filePath is null or empty then throw exception
- if filePath does not exist then throw exception
- if no valid postfixed '/' then add one
- if it contains a postfixed '\' then remove and replace with a '/'

Can someone tell me if there is a **framework** method that can do this(particularly the *forwareslash/backslash* logic) available to achieve this repetitive logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) method:

```
public string MakeFileNameUnique(string filePath, string fileName)
{
    return Path.Combine(filePath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), fileName);
}
```

but looking at the name of your method (`MakeFileNameUnique`), have you considered using the [`Path.GenerateRandomFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx) method? Or the [`Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) method?

Comment: Path.Combine takes just two parameters?

Comment: Yes, I considered using both Path.GenerateRandomFileName or the Path.GetTempFileName method but neither are sufficient for my needs.

Comment: @fin: `Path.Combine` can take any number of parameters, as one of its overloads is a `params` overload.  E.g., `Path.Combine()` is legal (albeit useless).  These overloads were added to .Net 4.0 .  For earlier versions, use nested calls to `Path.Combine`.

Answer (score 1):

Following your requirements this will do

```
public string MakeFileNameUnique(string filePath, string fileName)
{
    // This checks for nulls, empty or not-existing folders
    if(!Directory.Exists(filePath))
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();

    // This joins together the filePath (with or without backslash) 
    // with the Guid and the file name passed (in the same folder)
    // and replace the every backslash with forward slashes
    return Path.Combine(filePath, Guid.NewGuid() + "_" + fileName).Replace("\\", "/");
}
```

a call with

```
string result = MakeFileNameUnique(@"d:\temp", "myFile.txt");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

will result in

```
d:/temp/9cdb8819-bdbc-4bf7-8116-aa901f45c563_myFile.txt
```

However I wish to know the reason about the replace for the backslash with forward slashes

Comment: Wish to remove the mix of backslash and forwardslashes in the same path.